# Ember Routing misunderstanding

Tags: ember.js

I'm not fulling understanding the concept of routing in Ember,

based on the tutorial [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/), it says that the following definition,

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', function() {
    this.route('new');
  });
});
```

With the above route, we are going to have the following created:

```
Route Name:index
controller:IndexController
Route:IndexRoute
template:index
URL:/

Route Name:posts.index  
controller:PostsController->PostsIndexController
Route:PostsRoute
template:posts
URL:/posts

Route Name:posts.new    
controller:PostsController->PostsNewController
Route:PostsRoute->PostsNewRoute
template:posts->posts/new
URL:/posts/new
```

I have some questions regarding this:

1. What is the importance of having `PostsController` and `PostsIndexController`, For me, it's like the same thing? but surely it isn't else there wouldn't be two? So why are there two different controllers?
2. On that page, it says "Visiting `/posts` is slightly different. It will first render the `/posts` template. Then, it will render the `posts/index` template into the posts template's outlet." Are /posts and /posts/index template two different templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the importance of having PostsController and PostsIndexController, For me, it's like the same thing? but surely it isn't else there wouldn't be two? So why are there two different controllers?

PostsController is a controller for the `/posts` template. It will be used by `/posts/index` as well as `/posts/new`. Since both are rendered within `/posts`.

> On that page, it says "Visiting /posts is slightly different. It will first render the /posts template. Then, it will render the posts/index template into the posts template's outlet." Are /posts and /posts/index template two different templates?

Yes, they are. `/posts` can be seen as the common layout of `/posts/index` and `/posts/new`.